# Linked pair of sconces won't work without one regular bulb (can't put an LED in both)

Tags: walls, led, light

I have a problem with a pair of wall sconces that both operate from the same dimmer switch.  They both work fine with an incandescent in each.  When I put an LED in either, then neither work.  If I put an incandescent in one and an LED in the other, then they both work again.  It doesn't matter which has which, as long as it is one of each.  The LED bulbs are dimmable.  Is there a fix for this?  I would like LED in both.  Thanks.

Comment: Model # of dimmer? And if the answer is "I have no idea, the dimmer is old", then the answer is almost certainly: "Replace the dimmer with an LED-compatible dimmer".

Comment: not all bulbs are "dimmable" with all dimmers. higher quality LED bulbs tend to have the extra circuitry that allows them to work well with old dimmers that were designed for incandescent. Conversely, a newer dimmer will usually dim lower quality "dimmable" LED bulbs that don't seem to dim well on "regular" dimmers. New dimmers _and_ high-quality LED bulbs will give the best result, but using just one of those will generally give quite acceptable results.

Comment: if you don't want to replace the dimmer, buy a few packs of different bulbs and return the ones that don't work. if none work, get a new dimmer.

Comment: I have the same dimmer switches throughout the house where the bulbs are working.  I think it has something to do with the fixtures being wired in series vs parallel.  Anyone have experience with that?

Comment: It sounds like a dimmer that has a higher wattage requirement than the led’s allow. This is common with older dimmers not made for LED’s.  Remember that not only the led has to be dimmable but the dimmer must be compatible with the lamps. Check the model of dimmer it is most likely the problem.